# Is encrypted boot possible with syslinux?

Tags: boot, encryption, boot-loader, syslinux

I found that [Alpine uses syslinux boot loader by default](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Bootloaders). I'd like to know whether syslinux supports encrypted `/boot` just like GRUB2 does? (I'd like to use ZFS with native encryption instead of dm-crypt with btrfs if that is possible.)

Comment: I thought almost all encryption has some type of unencrypted bootloader (like syslinux itself), doesn't that affect your threat model more?

Comment: @Xen2050 No if you use secure boot. Not the best article, but I think you'll get the idea: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/take-control-your-pc-uefi-secure-boot?page=0,0